# WPF Binding Telerik Chartview

Tags: c#, sql-server, wpf, telerik

I have some data that is coming from a Stored procedure which i have been able to display in a non-Telerik DataGrid.  using the following code.

```
CBFdataDataContext conn = new CBFdataDataContext();
List<spTotalRevByZipResult> sptotalrevbyzipresult = (from s in conn.spTotalRevByZip() select s).ToList();

ZipGrid.ItemsSource = sptotalrevbyzipresult;
```

But with using the radCartesianChart, It says that there is no ItemSource.

```
<telerik:RadCartesianChart HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,104,0,0" Grid.Row="1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="723" Height="218" Name="ZipGrid">
           <telerik:RadCartesianChart.VerticalAxis>
               <telerik:LinearAxis/>
           </telerik:RadCartesianChart.VerticalAxis>
           <telerik:RadCartesianChart.HorizontalAxis>
               <telerik:CategoricalAxis/>
           </telerik:RadCartesianChart.HorizontalAxis>
           <telerik:RadCartesianChart.Series>
               <telerik:BarSeries CategoryBinding="subTotal"
                                  ValueBinding="custzip"
                                  ItemsSource="{Binding}"/>
           </telerik:RadCartesianChart.Series>
       </telerik:RadCartesianChart>
```

So How do i load the chart with Data?

```
CBFsqldataDataContext conn = new  CBFsqldataDataContext();

            List<spTotalRevByZipResult> sptotalrevbyzipresult = (from s in conn.spTotalRevByZip()

                                                                 select s).ToList();

            ZipGrid????????? = sptotalrevbyzipresult;
```

sample Data

```
custzip subTotal
NULL    18229530.07
123 0.00
674 0.00
1532    0.00
1701    0.00
1821    10860.08
1923    0.00
2134    0.00
2194    0.00
2715    2779.80
2876    72.00
3051    109.63
3060    186.00
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you go and read some documentation.

Here is a good link to [Telerik's RadCartesianChart using BarSeries](http://www.telerik.com/help/wpf/radchartview-series-barseries.html).

> You can use the following definition to display a simple BarSeries
>
> **XAML**
>
> ```
> <telerik:RadCartesianChart Palette="Windows8">
> <telerik:RadCartesianChart.HorizontalAxis>
>     <telerik:CategoricalAxis/>
> </telerik:RadCartesianChart.HorizontalAxis>
> <telerik:RadCartesianChart.VerticalAxis>
>     <telerik:LinearAxis />
> </telerik:RadCartesianChart.VerticalAxis>
> <telerik:RadCartesianChart.Series>
>     <telerik:BarSeries>
>         <telerik:BarSeries.DataPoints>
>             <telerik:CategoricalDataPoint Category="January" Value="2" />
>             <telerik:CategoricalDataPoint Category="February" Value="5" />
>             <telerik:CategoricalDataPoint Category="March" Value="3" />
>             <telerik:CategoricalDataPoint Category="April" Value="10" />
>             <telerik:CategoricalDataPoint Category="May" Value="9" />
>             <telerik:CategoricalDataPoint Category="June" Value="7" />
>             <telerik:CategoricalDataPoint Category="July" Value="1" />
>         </telerik:BarSeries.DataPoints>
>     </telerik:BarSeries>
> </telerik:RadCartesianChart.Series>
> </telerik:RadCartesianChart>
> ```

Comment: Well I did get something just not what I expected, I expected to see appox 450 bars.  I am only showing 1 does that mean I have to some how cycle through each of my columns and update the series for each row?

Comment: Hard to tell what's wrong... I'm pretty sure you don't have to cycle through each of your columns. Could you show what rows/columns `spTotalRevByZip()` is returning?

Comment: this is some sample data. 18229530.0700
123 0.0000
674 0.0000
1532 0.0000
1701 0.0000
1821 10860.0800
1923 0.0000
2134 0.0000
2194 0.0000
2715 2779.8000

Comment: Edit your question to include the sample data, and don't forget to specify column names in your example. Thanks

Comment: I edited my answer...but specify the COLUMN NAMES in your data sample example...Are you sure those 2 columns have the right names AND case (custzip and subTotal)?

Comment: Error 3 'Telerik.Windows.Controls.ChartView.CartesianSeries' does not contain a definition for 'CategoryBinding' and no extension method 'CategoryBinding' accepting a first argument of type 'Telerik.Windows.Controls.ChartView.CartesianSeries' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)Error 2 The type or namespace name 'DataRow' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)Error 4 The type or namespace name 'DataRow' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/20404/discussion-between-stephanm-and-francis-p)